# issue in logging in to Instagram using selenium, 'There was a problem logging you into Instagram'

Tags: python, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am writing a code to scrape Instagram, search and analyze the posts, likes, ...
My robot used to work correctly, but from yesterday it cannot login
I have tried all of these tricks:

- logging out from my previous account
- using proxies
- reset chromwebdriver

The language I'm using is python
libraries :

1. selenium
2. beatifulsoup

```py
    def fetch_element(self, by, string):
        res = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, string)))
        return res
```

```py
self.fetch_element(By.NAME, 'username').send_keys(username)
self.fetch_element(By.NAME, 'password').send_keys(password)
self.fetch_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div').click()
sleep(sleep_instagram)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of struggling I found that Instagram is sensitive to robot activities steps that I have one that has addressed this issue was to :
1- wait for random times

```py
import numpy as np
sleep_instagram = lambda t: np.random.randint(low=t / 2, high=t * 2, size=1)
```

2- click on the save login information

mine has been solved!!!